# lm35 Temperature Readings are not right after sealing with Hot-melt adhesive (How mush has it Soldering max Temp toleration ?)

Tags: tolerance, overheat, lm35

I need to seal the LM35 temp sensor so, I used this device for sealing it:

[image]

The code I have used are:

```
/*
 * PreciseLM35: A simple LM35 wrapper with optional voltage calibration facility
 * Version 1.0.2 (2017-04-30)
 * Written by belidzs
 * 
 * Features selectable reference voltage. 
 * Actual AREF value is polled from MCU, eliminating inaccuracies due to changing 
 * AREF value (depleting batteries, etc)
 *
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
 * version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * See file LICENSE for further informations on licensing terms.
 *
 * CalibratedDefaultRead.ino
 *
 * Use this if you need to measure temperatures higher than 110C or 
 * other analog sensor needs to read values higher than 1.1V. 
 * Otherwise CalibratedInternalRead gives you more accurate results
 *
 * Uses MCU's reported Vcc voltage instead of a nominal value of 3.3V or 5V
 * which can change over time due to depleting battery, unstable power
 * supply, etc.
 *
 * Calibration:
 * - First run with measuredVsReadAreFratio = 1.0
 * - Use a multimeter and measure voltage on AREF pin. It should be around 3.3V or 5V 
 *   depending on your Arduino
 * - Divide this value by the displayed AREF value and use it as measuredVsReadAreFratio
 * - Run the sketch again and check if serial terminal shows correct value for AREF
 * 
 */

#include <PreciseLM35.h>

const int pinLM35 = A0;
const float measuredVsReadArefRatio = 1.0; // enter here your ratio between measured and expected AREF
PreciseLM35 lm35(pinLM35, DEFAULT, measuredVsReadArefRatio);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Temp (C): " + String(lm35.readCelsius()));
  Serial.println("Temp (F): " + String(lm35.readFahrenheit()));
  Serial.println("AREF: " + String(lm35.readPreciseAref()));
  delay(2000);
}
```

So the result have been this kind:

[image]

the output is:

```
Te235.04
AREF: 4829
Temp (C): 113.70
Temp (F): 236.66
AREF: 4829
Temp (C): 97.60
Temp (F): 207.68
AREF: 4850
Temp (C): 87.20
Temp (F): 188.96
AREF: 4850
Temp (C): 82.40
Temp (F): 180.32
AREF: 4829
Temp (C): 77.70
Temp (F): 172.04
AREF: 4829
Temp (C): 73.90
Temp (F): 165.02
AREF: 4850
Temp (C): 65.40
Temp (F): 149.72
AREF: 4850
Temp (C): 62.50
Temp (F): 143.78
AREF: 4829
Temp (C): 59.70
Temp (F): 139.46
AREF: 4829
Temp (C): 55.70
Temp (F): 132.62
AREF: 4829
Temp (C): 57.50
Temp (F): 135.14
AREF: 4850
Temp (C): 53.50
Temp (F): 128.30
AREF: 4850
Temp (C): 59.20
Temp (F): 138.92
AREF: 4829
Temp (C): 56.10
Temp (F): 132.98
AREF: 4829
Temp (C): 61.30
Temp (F): 142.34
AREF: 4850
```

I have removed the adhesives from the lm35 sensor and could be seen here:

[image]

so the output backed to home temp 25 Centigrade degree like this:

```
Temp (C): 26.50
Temp (F): 79.70
AREF: 4850
Temp (C): 26.50
Temp (F): 79.52
AREF: 4829
Temp (C): 26.40
Temp (F): 79.52
AREF: 4850
Temp (C): 26.50
Temp (F): 78.08
AREF: 4850
Temp (C): 26.40
Temp (F): 79.52
AREF: 4829
Temp (C): 26.50
Temp (F): 80.60
AREF: 4850
Temp (C): 25.60
Temp (F): 81.32
AREF: 4829
Temp (C): 26.90
Temp (F): 79.52
AREF: 4829
Temp (C): 26.50
Temp (F): 78.08
AREF: 4850
Temp (C): 26.50
Temp (F): 80.42
AREF: 4829
Temp (C): 26.40
Temp (F): 79.70
AREF: 4850
Temp (C): 26.50
Temp (F): 79.70
AREF: 4829
Temp (C): 26.40
Temp (F): 79.52
AREF: 4829
Temp (C): 27.00
Temp (F): 80.60
AREF: 4850
Temp (C): 26.50
Temp (F): 79.70
AREF: 4829
Temp (C): 26.50
Temp (F): 80.42
AREF: 4850
Temp (C): 25.60
Temp (F): 79.70
AREF: 4850
Temp (C): 26.50
Temp (F): 79.52
AREF: 4829
Temp (C): 26.50
Temp (F): 79.70
AREF: 4850
Temp (C): 27.00
Temp (F): 79.70
AREF: 4829
Temp (C): 26.40
Temp (F): 79.52
AREF: 4850
Temp (C): 26.50
Temp (F): 79.70
AREF: 4850
```

I like to know why this happened ?and also I don't find the tolerance resistance for some actions like using hot-melt adhesives, in its [data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf)?

Thanks.

Comment: How long are your wires? Are you sure it's not oscillating due to capacitance of the cable?

Comment: No i have not changed my cable and its lent is almost 50 cm.

Comment: How long did you let the hot glue cool before doing measurements?

Comment: @moha_alpha-web.net The datasheet suggests 50pF as a maximum capacitive load unaided; a 50cm wire could exceed that, and the hot-glue could increase that number as well. I would not rule out oscillations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be some self-heating in the sensor. It consumes electrical power and warms itself up.

By adding a thermally insulating layer of plastic you have made it nearly impossible for that heat to escape. So, the sensor is going to get much warmer than the ambient temperature.

Comment: Thanks, It seems to be correct.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct at all. The datasheet mentions 114 µA maximum quiescent current. Assuming the output isn't loaded, that's a maximum of 570 µW dissipated at the arduino's 5 V. The readings show temperatures as high as ~115 °C, at an ambient of 25 °C, a delta of 90 K. That would require the hot glue to have a thermal resistance of roughly 16000 K/W, almost a thousand times higher than a TO-92 free-standing in air. I don't believe that for a second.

Comment: Thanks  @marcelm from your special view point, according your profile you could better know about i have asked for it here:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/462928/lm35-temperature-reading-increasing-with-hot-melt-adhesive-calculations-check-n